# How do I configure two NICs in ubuntu-server preseed?

Tags: server, system-installation, preseed, debian-installer

I have a script that installs Ubuntu server to a new VirtualBox instance via PXE and preseeding.  It works great, I can run a complete install and come out with a fresh machine with one network card.

How do I make the preseeded installation configure two or more network cards?

Will `d-i netcfg/choose_interface` will let me specify two devices?

I tried changing `/etc/network/interfaces` inside a `d-i preseed/late_command`, but I am having trouble getting it to work.

Is there a better way to give the virtual machine two NICs?

Comment: I completely disagree that this question is "too localized". Most servers have multiple NICs: 1-4 1GbE on-board, and with 10GbE, usually 2 on a PCIe card. I too would like suggestions on how best to enable them.

Comment: It is unfortunate that this was closed as "too localized", as I came to it seeking an answer to exactly the same question.

Comment: I've long since moved to vagrant for my use case, which exposes multiple NIC support sanely: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/vagrant-up/aNAlY4g3lWE

Comment: This question is important for VirtualBox because setting up 2 NICs is the typical means of allowing the Guest to access the Internet (interface configured as NAT using DHCP) and to also allow an ssh connection from the host to the guest using a knowable IP address (interface configured as host-only w/ static IP address configured in the guest os).

Comment: this is a useful question. Disappointing to see if closed.